# jquery mobile click h3 for popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

I'm trying to figure out how to open a popup menu when the user clicks on a heading (h3).

**(using jQuery 1.9.1 and jQM 1.3.1)**

HTML

```
<div data-role='header' data-theme='b'>
  <h3 data-rel='popup' href='#projectsOpen' id='projectName'>*Untitled</h3>
</div>


<div data-role='popup' id='projectsOpen' data-theme='a' class='ui-corner-all'>
  <ul data-role='listview' id='projectList'>
   <li><input type='radio' id='newproj' checked='checked'/><span>Create New Project</span></li>
   <li><input type='radio' id='project1'/><span id='project1Title'></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone shed some light on how I can do this?

Comment: With jQM the code is built-in when defining which divs are popups and which elements are the ones who open the popups. Supposedly, if you setup your HTML - jQM will initiate the code

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track then. Give it a try and see.

Comment: Well, thats the reason I posted this - I have no idea where to go from here

Comment: The documentation is your best friend. See [http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/) and [http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html). Though I haven't worked with jQuery Mobile before, I've just Googled for the documentation of this particular widget.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/p3wx8/ `$('#projectName').on('click', function () {
    $('#projectsOpen').popup('open');
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
It seems this fixs your issue..



<div data-role="page" id="p1"> 
      <div data-role='header' data-theme='b'>
      <h3 data-rel='popup' id='projectName'>*Untitled</h3>
    </div>   
    <div data-role='popup' id='projectsOpen' data-theme='a' class='ui-corner-all'>
      <ul data-role='listview' id='projectList'>
       <li><input type='radio' id='newproj' checked='checked'/><span>Create New Project</span></li>
       <li><input type='radio' id='project1'/><span id='project1Title'></span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div> 



 //jquery   

      $("#projectName").click(function(){
                $("#projectsOpen").popup("open");
        });


 you can observe here

    http://jsfiddle.net/N7Z9e/2254/
```